# Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0)

Tags: android, gradle

When running the app on Android Studio I get this error. Please help.

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2
         project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:15.0.2
         project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:15.0.1
         project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-phenotype:15.0.1
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-base.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

Comment: show your build.gradle please. Seems like need upgrade versions

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I was able to find the solution. See my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to find the solution and fix it. Here's the reference if anybody needs it:

https://forums.expo.io/t/expo-sdk-34-build-error-could-not-resolve-all-files-for-configuration-debugcompileclasspath/54429/2

Change:

```
maven { url 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer' }
```

To

```
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=exoplayer' }
```

Comment: The `web` URL is the maven explorer and NOT the maven URL required... It should be `https://maven.google.com`